# Steps to repair rotten 2 story wall

Tags: repair, structural, rot

So I have a porch that has significant rot due to a leaky skylight. This had been fixed with a new roof.

I found significant rot in the wall. This wall is load bearing and is supporting the roof. The wall holds rafters for a vaulted ceiling. Here is a [image: Picture]

I have the plans for the support wall. It will be a 2 story support wall about 3 feet inside.

My questions are? What order should I tackle this?

The top floor has rot along the top plates and headers. The bottom floors top plate is rotted along with the rim joist.

Should I kick out the entire wall once the support wall is up?

Can I do the repair in stages? Can the top plates be cut in half instead of one 15 foot top plate?

I assume I need to put a double top plate for the first/bottom story as there is only one top plate above the angled 2x12s.

I've had like 6 contractors come out. I've had problems with all of them. Either not knowing how to do it, not wanting a temp wall or refusing the repair and insisting a new porch is better. That and not having insurance.

I'm at whits end, and I just rather do it myself at this point.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! That's a bit of an issue you've got there! You're right to reject the guys who wouldn't want to put up a temporary wall - I don't know how they'd support this without one. Did those who "insist a new porch is better" give specific reasons or just dismiss the rebuild with the wave of a hand? If they gave specific reasons, they may well be pretty valid ones and you should at least give those reasons some serious consideration.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, it appears that you have 2x6 or maybe 2x8 "studs" set at an angle below the sliding glass door. Is that what I'm seeing? Was that, perhaps, originally a railing for the lower level as an open deck of some sort that the rest was built on top of at a later date? If that's the case, that _could_ be the reason some have recommended a complete rebuild...

Comment: They are angled 2x12s. 2X12s rest on a sill plate, and on top of them is a single top plate, then a rim joist. The top plate is rotted and the rim joist is rotted. I know how to repair the rim joist in stages, the top plate is what is throwing me off.

Comment: No specific reasons for the rebuild, other than I guess trying to sell me on a 20k porch.  Brand new roof and the rest of the walls are in decent shape. One or two of the rafters may need to be sistered.

Comment: 2x12 on an angle as studs. That's a _interesting_ wall system! I would think that if you know enough to be able to support the floor while you replace the rim joist, you can easily replace the top plate that said rim joist is sitting on at the same time. If it were me, I'd certainly build the crib walls, replace anything that needed to be replaced, then take down the crib walls. No sense in building them twice.